# str replace not work with dollar sign and html tags

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying replace some text in this string (add US before $ sign in ins tag)
ex-

```
$mystring='<del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>49.00</span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>39.00</span></ins>';


echo str_replace('<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>39.00</span></ins>','<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">US$</span>39.00</span></ins>',$mystring);
```

but it doesn't seems replace at all, i know there have woocmmerce functions to add prefix

but i need this without use those,

anyone know how to fix this or better method. thank you

the ourput should be
cuurent output is

<del>$49</del> $39

The output should be

<del>$49</del> US$39

Comment: Your output is `$49.00 US$39.00` with `$49.00` being stripped, Edit your question with the actual output and your desired output?

Comment: @OmariVictorOmosa thats only display output, i just want to replace second $ (the one within <ins> tag) replace with US$

Comment: @SunethKalhara Look into my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60427709/2667307

Comment: If you use a HTML DOM parser (DOMDocument usually does the job) then you can properly identify the content you need to change.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239).
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: @Toto why should we use whole php class when simply use star replace for above, i found answer without using above :)

Comment: Because generally, you can't parse HTML with regex. DOMDocument is the right tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please have a look, It will replace last occurrence of $ with US$ as per your required output.

```
$mystring='<del>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>49.00</span></del>
<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>39</span></ins>';

echo str_lreplace('$','US$',$mystring);
function str_lreplace($search, $replace, $subject)
{
    $pos = strrpos($subject, $search);

    if($pos !== false)
    {
       $subject = substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
    }

    return $subject;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it not works when pass above arguments but it works when i pass like this str_lreplace('<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">','<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">US',$mystring); i'll accept the answer

Comment: Glad it helped you! There is always go ahead scope! :)